# Как добавлять домен в закладки если находишься на поддомене?

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть страница https://sub1.site.ru/pravo.html, подскажите как сделать закладку(скрипт закладки) для пользователей что бы они находясь на https://sub1.site.ru/pravo.html могли добавить туже страницу только на основном домене https://site.ru/pravo.html ?